# Is there a Content Management System that allows multiple & independent blogs to be running on one domain?

Tags: cms, blog, content, management, system

I am a Wordpress fan, and I'm now building a new site and I'm not sure which CMS can achieve what I'm trying to do.

I am building a food blog network for a bunch of cities in the US, and I want to my city pages to be independently running blogs themselves. So basically...

- Home Page - Its own blog with its own users, talking about Food in general
- Dallas Page (child of home page) - Its own blog with its own users
- Chicago Page ..... so on and so forth.

The web layout and design will be all the same, but just trying to achieve 25~50 independent blogs on one domain.

How can I achieve this? I'm hoping that I don't have to install Wordpress into as many subdomains that I create.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Won't a WordPress Network do it?

http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network

Comment: I never knew such a thing existed. I will read it and get back to you! Thanks MrChrister!

Comment: You are the man. That is exactly what I needed. Never knew such a feature came with 3.0.

Comment: That would indicate this answers your question? Consider marking it as such :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be the [Lifetype](http://lifetype.net/) blogging platform, which accommodates multiple blogs and users.

I'm not sure if it has many CMS capabilities, but it handles multiple blogs and bloggers by default.